Bitnami Flink helm chart -Add external libraries to jobmanager and task manager
I am using the bitnami flink helm chart and developing a values.yaml (bitnami flink) and difficult to add the dependency jars through helm. I need to add the mssql cdc, iceberg, nessie jars to flink container . so that flink sql client will load them properly.
I am not sure how to do that.
I have tried to add it by spinning up a new init container and jars got downloaded into a folder and folder is accessiable in the flink container. but i need to copy that jars into /opt/bitnami/flink/lib..  How can i do that ?
I also tried to overwite the jobmanager command but it errored out saying config.yaml not found while starting the container.   My configuration jobmanager file is below
jobmanager:
  initContainers:
    - name: download-flink-dependencies
      image: busybox:latest
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      command:
        - /bin/sh
        - -c
        - |
          echo "Downloading dependencies..."
          DEPENDENCY_URL="https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/iceberg/iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17/1.5.2/iceberg-flink-runtime-1.17-1.5.2.jar"
          wget -P /opt/flink/job $DEPENDENCY_URL
          echo "Dependencies downloaded."
      volumeMounts:
        - name: flink-job
          mountPath: /opt/flink/job
  extraVolumeMounts:
    - name: flink-job
      mountPath: /opt/flink/job
  extraVolumes:
    - name: flink-job
      emptyDir: {}
  extraEnvVars:
    - name: FLINK_CFG_STATE.CHECKPOINTS.DIR
      value: "s3p://flink/checkpoints"
    - name: FLINK_CFG_STATE_SAVEPOINTS_DIR
      value: "s3p://flink/savepoints"
    - name: FLINK_CFG_STATE_BACKEND_TYPE
      value: filesystem
    - name: FLINK_CFG_S3_AWS__ACCESS__KEY
      value: admin
    - name: FLINK_CFG_S3_AWS__SECRET__KEY
      value: password
    - name: FLINK_CFG_S3_ENDPOINT
      value: http://10.31.147.70:9000
    - name: FLINK_CFG_S3_PATH_STYLE_ACCESS
      value: "true"
    - name: HADOOP_CLASSPATH
      value: /opt/flink/job
  # command:
  #   - /bin/sh
  #   - -c
  #   - |
  #     chmod
  #     # Copy files to the Flink library path
  #     cp /opt/flink/job/*.jar /opt/bitnami/flink/lib/
  #     # Start the Flink JobManager
  #     /opt/bitnami/flink/bin/jobmanager.sh start
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 2
      memory: 2048Mi
    requests:
      cpu: 250m
      memory: 1024Mi

